# Is Poynting flux the same as the Poynting vector?

Tags: electrical-engineering, electromagnetism

I need to solve a homework question that asks me to find the Poynting flux. However, I can't find any formulas for Poynting flux anywhere. Is the Poynting flux the same as the Poynting vector?

Comment: `find the Poynting flux` ... is that really the assignment you were given?

Comment: The question states: find the flux of the Poynting vector through an arbitrary cross section of the cable – in the following four ways, respectively